# Refreshing a PHP include?

Tags: php, ajax, facebook, include

I'm creating a PHP game, within the game there is a section at the top of the page showing the users how much energy they have left, this is a file 'header.php'

There is a page where users can go to they gym to train their skills, training their skills decrease their energy.

At the moment the gym page has to be refreshed so that header.php can reload to reflect their new energy level, is there anyway of refreshing just the header.php and not the whole page?

I hope you understand,

Thanks,

Jack.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this if you are "including" the page using php. Php is server side. By the time it has got to the client browser it has been parsed and sent as HTML.

You will have to use ajax. Probably the best way to use ajax is to have the "energy" sent as a json string (or similar) and change the number using javascript.

I don't know what you can use if you're using facebook (you have this as a tag) but if you can use jquery it would be good to look up jquery's $.ajax function.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of refreshing the whole header, you can use some jquery/ajax script to refresh and show energy level.